# how to read integer int* from text in c

Tags: c, file, text, integer, int

I have this structure and a structure for AVL tree

```
struct imobil
{
    unsigned int id;
    char *streetName;
    unsigned int streetNumber;
    int noApartaments;
    int *noPeopleLivingInApartaments;
    float totalValue;
};

struct nodeAVL
{
    imobil inf;
    nodeAVL *right;
    nodeAVL *left;
    int BF;
};
```

What i want to do is to populate this AVL structure with some text from txt file, and it crashes when i try to read that integer int*.

```
void main()
{
 FILE *f = fopen("Imobil.txt", "r");
 int n;
 nodeAVL *root = (nodeAVL*)malloc(sizeof(nodeAVL));
 imobil imob;
 char buffer[20];

fscanf(f, "%d", &n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    fscanf(f, "%d", &root->inf.id);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &root->inf.streetNumber);
    fscanf(f, "%s", &buffer);
    root->inf.streetName= (char*)malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(root->inf.streetName, buffer);
    fscanf(f, "%f", &root->inf.totalValue);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &root->inf.noApartaments);
    for (int i = 0; i < root->inf.noApartaments;i++)
        fscanf(f, "%d", &root->inf.noPeopleLivingInApartaments[i]);
    inserare(imob, root);
}
fclose(f);
preorder(root);
deallocation(root);
}
```

Comment: You definitively do not want to read an `int *` from a file! You might want to read an `int`, though.

Comment: @xing now it says that "imob is used without being initialized". and if i do     imobil imob=NULL; i have an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate space for `noOfPeopleLivingInApartments` before you can read into the elements.

```
root->inf.noPeopleLivingInApartaments = malloc(root->inf.noApartaments * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < root->inf.noApartaments;i++) {
    fscanf(f, "%d", &root->inf.noPeopleLivingInApartaments[i]);
}
```